# How to find private static methods in static class using reflection?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, static

I have a static class and I want to find its private static methods using typeof(MyStaticClass).GetMethods() but it always shows me the public methods only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you see the `BindingFlags`-overload? Just use `GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overload of `GetMethods` that includes a `BindingFlags` parameter:

```
var methods = typeof(MyStaticClass)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

(I haven't included `BindingFlags.Instance` as you've explicitly said it's a static class; to find all methods in any class, include that as well.)

Comment: it works, I was not using combined flags. Thanks @Jon